# Why was Amarendra Baahubali calm while being removed from his position as army commander?

Tags: plot-explanation, baahubali-2-the-conclusion

In the movie *Baahubali: The Conclusion*, Amarendra Baahubali was removed from his position by his king brother Bhallaladeva.

Even Devasena talked about it and Sivagami is thinking about it. But why did Baahubali just follow orders without any questions on such injustice? Even though his brother is king, he is supposed to ask for reasons for such an order due to the silly reason told by Bhallaladeva.

Which quality of Baahubali made him calm during that incident?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Because it is his duty to follow the orders of his king.

As being Army Commander, it was his duty to follow the orders of his king, who apparently was Bhallaldeva.

This is one of traits of Baahubali that he obeys rules of Maahismati without hesitation which we have seen throughout both movies and he also took oath over it. Therefore, he is just doing his duty without questioning anything.